# How do I get multiple JSON strings to render as a dataframe with python?

Tags: python, json, api, response, spotify

I am trying to get audio_feature data on a list of Spotify songs [using their API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-audio-features/). After getting my API token, I make a request on the API will the following code

```
    header2 ={
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+token.json()['access_token']    
}
param2 = {
    'ids' : '7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo,6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF,22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD'

}
response = requests.get(endpoint,headers=header2,params=param2)
response.status_code
response.json()
```

which gives me this response

```
{'audio_features': [{'danceability': 0.297,
   'energy': 0.827,
   'key': 5,
   'loudness': -4.748,
   'mode': 1,
   'speechiness': 0.0735,
   'acousticness': 0.12,
   'instrumentalness': 0.000123,
   'liveness': 0.347,
   'valence': 0.467,
   'tempo': 147.232,
   'type': 'audio_features',
   'id': '7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo',
   'uri': 'spotify:track:7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo',
   'track_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo',
   'analysis_url': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo',
   'duration_ms': 221773,
   'time_signature': 4},
  {'danceability': 0.778,
   'energy': 0.317,
   'key': 1,
   'loudness': -10.732,
   'mode': 0,
   'speechiness': 0.334,
   'acousticness': 0.592,
   'instrumentalness': 0,
   'liveness': 0.0881,
   'valence': 0.327,
   'tempo': 140.048,
   'type': 'audio_features',
   'id': '6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF',
   'uri': 'spotify:track:6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF',
   'track_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF',
   'analysis_url': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF',
   'duration_ms': 178627,
   'time_signature': 4},
  {'danceability': 0.842,
   'energy': 0.734,
   'key': 1,
   'loudness': -5.065,
   'mode': 0,
   'speechiness': 0.0588,
   'acousticness': 0.0427,
   'instrumentalness': 0,
   'liveness': 0.106,
   'valence': 0.952,
   'tempo': 137.958,
   'type': 'audio_features',
   'id': '22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD',
   'uri': 'spotify:track:22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD',
   'track_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD',
   'analysis_url': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD',
   'duration_ms': 181027,
   'time_signature': 4}]}
```

**I now really want to convert these three JSON records to a table with the columns that are currently present as labels for each track. How do I create such a table?**

I have run into errors using json.dumps() and only get strings for each JSON record when I use the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=response.json(),)
print(df)
```

Comment: 1) Try put the list `response.json()['audio_features'] rather than the full dictionary. 2) You may want to give the error log so that we can find the incorrection in or "json" 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `pandas` right out of the box by using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

json_normalize(data, record_path='audio_features')

   acousticness                                       analysis_url  ...                                   uri  valence
0        0.1200  https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/7C5U...  ...  spotify:track:7C5UlMz9b51rQI66lpEiSo    0.467
1        0.5920  https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6ocb...  ...  spotify:track:6ocbgoVGwYJhOv1GgI9NsF    0.327
2        0.0427  https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/22vg...  ...  spotify:track:22vgEDb5hykfaTwLuskFGD    0.952
```

In `pandas>=1.0.0` it is just `from pandas import json_normalize`